# DirectQuery - Very inefficient queries being generated to Snowflake

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am connecting PBI to Snowflake using DirectQuery. To keep it simple, I have two tables, a product dimension table and a sales fact table. There are 3.7M rows in the product dimension table and 100M in the sales fact table. I also have a measure that calculates total sales which uses SUM to sum a column in the fact table.

I create a table visual in PBI and put the product description as the first column. The query generated by PBI is good. It retrieves 501 rows and displays them. So far, so good. Next I put the total sales measure as the second column. Now PBI generates several queries retrieving 1,000,001 rows. Of course I get an error stating the 1M row limit for DirectQuery has been reached.

This should not be happening. Has anyone run into something like this? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I do not have experience with Snowflake, but it looks like the [query folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-folding) doesn't work. Try to find why it doesn't work in your case - check how you connect to the datasource, what transformations are made, etc.

Comment: Thanks Andrey - I know it's not a transformation affecting query folding issue because I'm not doing any transformations on the dimension table.

Answer (score -1):

I had a dig around and there is a capability to adjust the limit if you have a premium license

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/five-new-power-bi-premium-capacity-settings-is-available-on-the-portal-preloaded-with-default-values-admin-can-review-and-override-the-defaults-with-their-preference-to-better-fence-their-capacity/

Comment: You missed the point. I never said I wanted to increase the limit. The queries being sent to Snowflake are very suboptimal.

Comment: no i didn't miss the point, if you are pushing the limit then you need to aggregate before grabbing the result. Pretty standard really.